# Currency symbol doesn't appear properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have on database table

```
----------
id currency currency_symbol

1    euro       `&euro;`  
2    yen        `&yen;`
----------
```

when i fetch it from php it works well. but when i repalce currency symbol in HTML by javascript it prints `&euro;` not `&euro;` exact symbol.

Comment: Yeah, because the text is `&euro;` and not "€". You should not store HTML entities in your database. Store "€" directly in your database, because then you can simply print what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use `html_entity_decode` function. It decodes html entities.

```
ex: echo html_entity_decode('&euro;') //outputs '€' symbol
```